# Repeated images shown on Flask app (Using base64)

Tags: python, image, flask

I doing a web app for a simple telecommunications stuff, and I'm having some problems.
This is my code for showing diagrams for Bit Error Rate of BPSK and DPSK.

BPSK:

```
@app.route('/bpsk')
def bpsk():
img = io.BytesIO()
EbN0_dB = []
loi = []
i = 0
while i <= 24:
    EbN0_dB.append(i)
    i += 1
for item in EbN0_dB:
    EbN0 = 10**(item/10)
    BER = 1/2*erfc(sqrt(EbN0))
    loi.append(BER)

plt.semilogy(EbN0_dB, loi, 'c-s', label = "BPSK")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('BER')
plt.xlabel('Eb/N0 (dB)')
plt.title('Bit Error Rate for Binary Phase-Shift Keying')
plt.savefig(img, format='png')
img.seek(0)

plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()

return render_template('plot.html', plot_url=plot_url)
```

DPSK:

```
@app.route('/dpsk')
def dpsk():
imga = io.BytesIO()
EbN0_dB = []
loi = []
i = 0
while i <= 24:
    EbN0_dB.append(i)
    i += 1
for item in EbN0_dB:
    EbN0 = 10**(item/10)
    BER = 1/2*exp(-EbN0)
    loi.append(BER)

plt.semilogy(EbN0_dB, loi,'m-s', label = "DPSK")
plt.legend()

plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('BER')
plt.xlabel('Eb/N0 (dB)')
plt.title('Bit Error Rate for Differential Phase Shift Keying')
plt.savefig(imga, format='png')
imga.seek(0)

plot_urla = base64.b64encode(imga.getvalue()).decode()

return render_template('plot.html', plot_url=plot_urla)
```

plot.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block app_content %}
<h1> This is a chart I just created! </h1>
<br>
<body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url }}">
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the result I got: [BPSK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkZLx.png)
[DPSK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q57UX.png)

As you can see, when I first showed BPSK diagram, it was ok. But when I came to DPSK one, the previous blue line of BPSK diagram did not disappear, it was still there with the new purple line of DPSK. How can I only show new images without remaining the previous ones?